# Input Value Dependencies

Tags: input, sliders, fields

I currently have a slider as shown in the image below.

[image: Annuity Vs Drawdown Slider]

If the user adjusts the Drawdown value the Annuity value is affected also and vice versa. This
sounds simple, however, if a user wants to increase say the Annuity amount via the slider, they tend to drag the pointer towards Annuity, which actually increases the Drawdown value and reduces the Annuity value.

Originally, the slider contained two colours which helped a little but due to the constraints of our system the colours can not be added.

[image]

Can someone please advise on how this should be done.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Go with the flow**

Seems to me your users are telling you the solution: make right motion increase the annuity proportion.

You see the slider as some kind of horizontal stacked bar chart, but your users don't. They see it like a car's AC/heat control. So don't fight it.

**Make a stacked bar chart more like a stacked bar chart**

If you really must have the gap between the text boxes represent proportions, you can try making it more like a stacked bar chart --turn the slider sideways. Make the track wide. And, yes use the colors. Color the text box labels and values to match the "bar" colors to make the association. Put the labels beside the bars, not at the extremes of the slider (top and bottom for a vertical one), so it's associated with the bars more than the direction of motion. Dynamic brackets may help.

[image]

Obviously, this would need to be a custom-made control (e.g., in Flash), which may not be worth the development resources. I'm skeptical you'll have sufficient success using a standard slider because the whole problem is you're making a slider that works opposite of what users expect of a slider (where sliding towards a label at one end gets "more" of it). To avoid that problem you need to make the control *not look like* a standard slider.

Only a usability test is going to tell you whether going vertical, thicker, moving the labels and text boxes, matching the colors, and adding dynamic brackets is going to get users thinking "this is a stack bar" rather than "this is like an AC/heater control," but it sounds like you're doing usability testing so you can find out for your users.

FWIW, I tried the drawing below on five people in my office this morning (including one small re-design iteration), asking "What would you do if you wanted to increase the Annuity to 75%?" One-and-a-half said they'd pull the slider up. Three-and-half said they'd pull the slider down. ("Half" because one user changed her mind from "up" to "down" after looking more closely at it). I'd say it still needs work, but maybe it's better than what you were getting with an ordinary slider, so, again, if you feel you *must*  have the gap between the text boxes represent proportions, then this approach may be a good starting point.

The more general advice is that if you're going to use a metaphor or association, like "stacked bar graph," then the more your graphics invoke that metaphor/association, the better it will work.

**No slider**

Maybe you don't want a slider at all. Sliders are best when the user is making an adjustment to the point where it "looks good" (or sounds good, in the case of an audio presentation), rather than trying to achieve a specific value known beforehand. Before, during, or after making the setting, sliders are great for giving users an at-a-glance general impression of where they are on a scale.

However, if users almost always arrive at the page with specific value in mind, you may be better off with simply two text boxes. Sliders are kind of a pain to get to a precise value (e.g., exactly 33%), and aren't so good at checking a precise value (33% versus 30%). Using text boxes also saves real estate. User research will tell you what the deal is.

Two editable text boxes can be coordinated so that changes to one update the other in real time to keep the percents totaling 100. See, for example, how Google coordinates the texts boxes for its Unit Converter (Google, say, "[meters to feet](https://www.google.com/search?q=meters%20to%20feet&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" to see it).

Put the text boxes together in a frame labeled "Drawdown vs. Annuity" so users will be more likely to see them as associated. That's about all Google does and may be all that's necessary. If it causes confusion, it might help to have static read-only text below the two text boxes showing they (always) total 100%. If you're up for building a custom control you could try adding a small *noninteractive* graphic between the text boxes showing relative proportions. I'd go with a pie graph rather than a stacked bar to avoid confusion with a slider.

Of course, you can have both the slider and the editable text boxes if some of your users are going by looks while others have a value in mind beforehand. In fact, I assumed that's what you were doing.

**Mumbles to self**

Why can I never give a short simple answer? Maybe I should've stopped with the first sentence.

Comment: I think that adding the contrasting color backgrounds actually throws in a potentially confusing element that contradicts the typical user expectations of the slider interface. Great point about just following what your users are telling you and letting the %'s tell the story (in case it's not clear from the slider position).

Comment: I think the problem with the (absence of) colors is that their framework doesn't support it. So, a technical issue, and I doubt that your concept would be feasible to implement. Not saying it's not a good idea (though perhaps placing it vertically might waste space) just that it'll probably not really help the OP.

Comment: I actually don't understand how this slider is an improvement on the original. The only difference here is that it has been positioned vertically.

Comment: , which as stated by @PixelSnader, wastes space.

The colour helps to emphasise the size of the values but as mentioned in the original post - there is a technical constraint with adding colours.

Putting the slider idea aside and thinking in a different light. 
What about having one input field value for say Drawdown and have the Annuity field calculate itself automatically?
How do I clearly define that association to the user?

Comment: @Michael - lol that's ok, I really appreciate the thought that has gone into it. We have come up with an alternative this end but we wont know whether it works for sure until we user test it. I shall post it shortly. 
Cheers

Comment: @Radders - Heh-heh, yes I kept thinking of stuff to address the comments, and adding it below illustration. I can get a little obsessive about these things. Maybe others in a similar situation will make use of it.